# How to add comment in using office js in window office js 2016?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-addins

I am working with office js. added my add-in comment in the cell is working properly with mac office and office 365 but I can't insert comments in windows pc office which version of office 2016.
what did I do wrong? Please guide me thanks. here is my code snippet

```
await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
   let wb = ctx.workbook;
    await ctx.sync().then(async () => {
            try {
                const address="sheet!A4"
              var comment = wb.comments.getItemByCell(address);
              comment.delete();
              wb.comments.add(address, "This is simple test comment");
            } catch (error) {
              if (error.code == Excel.ErrorCodes.itemNotFound) {
                wb.comments.add(address, "This is simple test comment");
                console.log("Add comment successfully!");
              }
            }
          
        });
        await ctx.sync();
    });
```

[image]

Comment: This `await ctx.sync().then(async () =>` looks so messy. can you remove the awaits and check?

Comment: I have removed then I had checked still it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel 2016 installed to test, but I do see a couple of problems and when I correct them and run in Excel 365, it works ok.

First, you have an issue with the scope or your "address" constant.  Because it is declared in the "try" block it is not available in the "catch" block.  Either move its declaration above the try/catch structure or change it from "const" to "var".

The second issue I see is that if there is an error because there is no comment on cell A4 of Sheet1, the error won't happen until the ctx.sync() statement is executed, which is outside the "try" block, so the "catch" will not be invoked.  Here's the corrected code that works fine on Excel 365.

```
function test_comment(){
  Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
    let wb = ctx.workbook;
    try {
      var address="Sheet1!A4"
      var comment = wb.comments.getItemByCell(address);
      comment.delete();
      wb.comments.add(address, "This is simple test comment");
      await ctx.sync();
      console.log("Replace comment successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code == Excel.ErrorCodes.itemNotFound) {
        wb.comments.add(address, "This is simple test comment");
        await ctx.sync();
        console.log("Add comment successfully!");
      }
    }
  });
}
```